# HashSet retainAll using interface

Tags: java, collections, equals

I have some code where I try to use the `HashSet.retainAll()` function.

In the example code below, the `HashSet` contains the interface `IPerson`, but the equals functions in object `Person` is never reached. I have even tried to expose the equals function in the interface and several other things. I feel I have tried everything. How can I make `retainAll()` use my implemented equal function?

```
class Person implements IPerson {
  private String name;
  public Person(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj){
    System.out.println("calling equals");
    return super.equals(Object obj);
  }

}

HashSet<IPerson> persons1 = new HashSet<IPerson>();
persons1.add(new Person("Jane"));
persons1.add(new Person("Joel"));
persons1.add(new Person("Joe"));

HashSet<IPerson> persons2 = new HashSet<IPerson>();
persons2.add(new Person("Jane"));
persons2.add(new Person("Joel"));

persons1.retainAll(persons2);
// expect sysout from Person.equals()

System.out.println(persons1.size());
// prints 0
```

Comment: What is `super.equals(Object obj);` doing? `private name;` is another one ... Please at least care to post compilable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `hashCode` because the hashset uses the hashcode to find the right 'bucket' first and only calls equals after it finds something in it. That's why your equals method is never called. (if you don't override the hashcode method, it gives every new object a different hashcode, so even if you call `new Person("name")` twice with the same name they won't have the same hashcode)

Comment: Yes the problem was indeed the hashCode which additionally (obviously) had to consider the case sensitivity. I.e `return getName().toLowerCase().hashCode();`

Answer (score 4):

you need to consider `name` to check `equal`ity and include it to compute `hashCode` also make sure you follow [`hashcode` and `equals` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

Comment: Just as hint: you can easily create this both methods by using Eclipse -> Source -> Generate hashcode() and equals()