# Is checking hashCode() equality a valid approach to implement equals(Object obj)?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

My `hashCode` method ensures that equal objects have equal hash codes.  My implementation also guarantees that the contrapositive is true, in that equal hash codes imply object equality.  Doing something like:

```
   @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {return true;}
        if (obj == null) {return false;}
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {return false;}
        return (obj.hashCode() == this.hashCode());
    }
```

seems an obvious choice, but I don't see this often.  Is this is a good idea in my case, or am I missing something?

Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the `hashCode` and `equals` methods are in generated classes (and obviously are themselves generated).  The reason I mention this is to highlight the fact that these methods will not be maintained manually per say.  They are in classes that are created at compile time and are not intended to be changed unless the schema they are based on changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374127/hashset-retainall-using-interface/24374163#24374163

Comment: I think that if you can *guarantee* a perfect `hashCode()` implementation, then this is OK. So in your case, it's fine, as your implementation guarantees that collisions won't occur. In the general case, though, it probably shouldn't be done.

Comment: "My hashCode method ensures that equal objects have equal hash codes. My implementation also guarantees that the contrapositive is true.." - *then there is **no** question*; `equals` can be defined in terms of `hashCode` for *this* implementation per the axioms stated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If, as the question says, your `hashCode` implementation really does guarantee that unequal objects have unequal hash codes, then in principle there is nothing wrong with what you are doing. Your `equals` method is checking a property that is equivalent to equality, so the behavior is as intended. You should re-check that guarantee, though; remember that no matter how clever you are, you can only store 32 bits of information in an int, which means that most non-trivial objects will necessarily have hash colisions.

However, there are a few caveats. First is clarity: if you implement `equals` this way, anyone using your code has to look at your `hashCode` implementation to find out what properties determine equality. Second is speed: if your hash code implementation is significantly slower than simply checking equality of the relevant properties (including boolean shortcutting in that calculation), then it may be worth re-implementing the logic in the `equals` function to avoid the speed penalty. Third is coupling: implementing `equals` in this manner means that it depends on that property of `hashCode`, and any future change to `hashCode` has to either preserve that property or move the logic into `equals`.

Comment: +1 For being the only answer to directly address the assertions made by the OP (which really means this "question" is really "not a question").

Comment: I would comment both methods noting their relationship. A future maintainer might increase the number of possible values, leading to hashCode collisions, or panic because depending on distinct hashCode values is a common bug in equals implementation.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan "My hashCode method ensures that equal objects have equal hash codes. My implementation also guarantees that the contrapositive is true." (Design decisions aside, the OP has already claimed to have addressed / eliminated / been-aware-of such.)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I added a third point addressing that problem.

Comment: @user2864740 That the writer of a piece of code is aware of something at the time it is being written is no guarantee even that the writer will be aware of it five years from now, when adding a new feature that increases the number of states. It certainly does not guarantee that a different programmer will be aware of it. Turning that awareness into comments would be more effective.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thanks for the answer. Your third point about coupling is a huge concern.  I decided to not go with an approach that uses hashCode() in equals(Object obj).

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good idea. While two objects which are equal must have the same hash code, the opposite is not true: 2 objects with the same hash code may not be equal. As a simple example, consider `Long`. The hash code returns an `int`, so it is not possible to represent with an int all possible `long` values. This means that many `Long` objects are not equal, but have the same hash code.

Answer (score 2):

If, and only if, your contrapositive guarantee holds then you can test equality that way.  In the general case your contrapositive does not hold and equality is not guaranteed.  In particular someone may override the `hashCode()` method so your contrapositive no longer holds.  Far better to use a more traditional equality test which compares significant fields.

Your code is fragile, and depends critically on a very specific property of your `hashCode()` implementation which is not part of the general `hashCode()` contract.  You can always use non-matching hash codes to detect inequality.  It is not good practice to use equal hash codes to assume equality.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes (though rarely), hash codes can result in collisions; you are probably aware of this!

As a result of that, it's a good idea to base equality on other features of the objects being compared (perhaps in addition to the hash code).

Answer (score -2):

No, the hash is used to distribute your objects in a collection, they are not unique. For example, a collection would use the hashcode to identify a bucket to place your object. The bucket itself is a List of all objects with similar hash codes. The purpose is for efficiency in lookups where order is unimportant.

It is important to build your hash using the same attributes for equality to ensure that 2 semantically equal objects end up in the same bucket

Comment: First sentence in the question: "My `hashCode` method ensures that equal objects have equal hash codes". So in this case, they *are* unique.

Comment: I don't mind being down-voted, but I'd prefer to know why, so that I can learn :) - @user3580294, while your implementation of hashCode may be safe, the practice won't be in the general case, as others have pointed out. You may wish to read Effective Java by Joshua Bloch for best-practice approaches

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were the OP!

Comment: No problem! Happens to all of us.